# I want to share the details of webapp to native facebook app

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web-applications, flipkart-api

I tried every possible answer on S/O, but not able to navigate from my webapp to native facebook app,

but when I checked **flipkart site on my mobile** they provide that functionality to navigate to native facebook app if it is installed in mobile phone otherwise it opens the facebook on browser ***(while sharing the product info)***.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are referring to here, but I guess you might be looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share …?

Comment: yes @CBroe I checked that thanks for your help. but i want to share only on facebook native app if it is installed on device.. using navigator.share method will open all the apps on which we can share...I need only facebook in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook didn't provide any such solution on their [facebook developer platform](https://developers.facebook.com/). I tried various ways which was posted on S/O, but none of them is working correctly now. In android it only opens the facebook app and not post or feed anything, and ios it gives the error i.e file path is incorrect.